# C# WinForm - EXE not terminating when closing main form

Tags: c#, winforms, process, oledb

I am developing a WinForms application that uses OleDB (along with NPOI) extensively to read and write Excel workbooks. I will preface this by saying that if I just launch the app and close it immediately, the application and the EXE terminate fine.  The first action the user can perform is to click on a button to open an XLSX file.  I then initialize a datatable in memory and use the following code to populate it :

Open connection :

```
public static OleDbConnection GetConnection(string filePath)
    {
        var url = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source=" + filePath + ";" +
            "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES; IMEX=1;';";

        try
        {
            var con = new OleDbConnection(url);

            con.Open();

            return con;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to open connection to workbook with url \"{url}\"", e);
        }
    }
```

Fill datatable :

```
public static void PopulateDataTable(string filePath, DataTable dt)
    {
        using var con = GetConnection(filePath);

        using var sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + GetSheetName(con) + "]", con));
        sda.Fill(dt);
        sda.Dispose();

        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

The first method is only used to validate the headers of the file and IS closed and disposed explicitly by the calling code.  It is also in a using block, I do realize there is some redundancy there but I am desperate.

Once the file is proven valid against a pre-determined list of column headers, the second method is called.  As soon as this action is performed, closing the main form SEEMS to close the app but there is still a lingering process in task manager with a single thread in it.

I have tried adding `Application.Exit()` and `Environment.Exit(0)` to the FormClosing method which does kill the process but not before showing an hourglass and logging the following error in event viewer :

```
Faulting application name: SomeApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x62cf0b31
Faulting module name: mso20win32client.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x62df2f51
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x000185ed
Faulting process id: 0x27f24
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8bc7d9dd155ac
Faulting application path: C:\Dev\VisualStudioProjects\SomeApp\Final\SomeApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office16\mso20win32client.dll
Report Id: 4a58bd92-6541-4def-a04d-01ed0668d38b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

A second event is also logged that is identical except for the exception code which is 0xc0000005.  I suspect this issue is also responsible for a false positive detection from Windows Defender.  I cannot figure out what this lingering thread is and how to get the code to properly kill it.

Comment: This is not the problem, but just a FYI: You don't need to dispose AND close AND use "using" for an IDisposable. Your `using var con = GetConnection(filePath);` should suffice - you don't need to call `.Close()` or `.Dispose()`.

Comment: I think the issue is with the version of ACE.  ACE is a Office product that is used as the driver for connecting your c# to the Office product Excel.  It looks like you do not have Office 12 installed so you have version 16 of office installed and using a conversion assistance to access office 12.  The ACE version should be the same as the version of office installed on your machine.  So I would change connection string to ACE 16 and see what happens.

Comment: Note that `OleDbCommand` is actually disposable, but Microsoft never seem to dispose it in their code samples. Nevertheless, it might be worth disposing it, just in case...

Comment: disposing of the command explicitly did not help.

Comment: and also I was calling close and dispose out of sheer desperation, understood they are redundant here.  I will remove them once I find the issue

Comment: `I was calling close and dispose out of sheer desperation` Been there, done that :)

Comment: changing to ACE.OleDB.16 gives me "could not find installable ISAM" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by implementing a purely NPOI-based reading solution without using OleDB (good riddance) :

```
public static void PopulateDatatableNPOI(string filePath, DataTable dt, bool createHeaders)
    {
        using var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        var sheet = new XSSFWorkbook(stream).GetSheetAt(0);

        if (createHeaders)
        {
            var headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0);
            foreach (var headerCell in headerRow)
                dt.Columns.Add(headerCell.ToString());
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < sheet.PhysicalNumberOfRows; i++)
        {
            var sheetRow = sheet.GetRow(i);
            var dtRow = dt.NewRow();
            dtRow.ItemArray = dt.Columns
                .Cast<DataColumn>()
                .Select(c => sheetRow.GetCell(c.Ordinal, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).ToString())
                .ToArray();
            dt.Rows.Add(dtRow);
        }
    }
```

The EXE terminates properly now!